# Can Tor be used to log in skype when it is blocked at work place?

Tags: censorship

Can Tor be used to log in skype when it is blocked at my work place?
At the work place when skype is blocked, how can I use skype? will Tor help me?

Answer (score 3):

Trying to circumvent anything that's blocked at your workplace may get you fired. And in any case, Tor isn't a good choice for Skype. That's because Skype works best using UDP for voice data, and Tor doesn't handle UDP traffic.

Your best bet is asking IT support about this. If you're determined to go it alone, you'll have better results with a VPN service, which can handle UDP traffic, and will be much faster.